# Learning rate in tensorflow Adadelta

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow

In the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5701), introducing the *Idea 2* eliminates the learning rate.

So what is the meaning of learning rate in tensorflow [implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdadeltaOptimizer)?

`Class AdadeltaOptimizer`:

```
__init__(
    learning_rate=0.001,
    rho=0.95,
    epsilon=1e-08,
    use_locking=False,
    name='Adadelta'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just multiplies the variable updates (see [the update op implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/04b5c75aae4bdbdac7c713714a369f9b360daf70/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc#L79)).

For any "automatic learning rate" scheme, you can always scale the resulting updates by a constant (whether it's necessary to do so is a separate issue).

Answer (score 0):

Adadelta optimizer has a way to adaptively change learning rate but still, it needs an initial value of learning rate.
Although as you can see in tensorflow [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/training/adadelta.py) to achieve the exact results of Adadelta paper you should set it to 1.0:

> learning_rate: A `Tensor` or a floating point value. The learning rate.
>           To match the exact form in the original paper use 1.0.

Comment: There is no such a thing as an _initial value_ of learning rate in the paper. Look at the formula (14) - no learning rate at all.